# Bower not installing on zsh

Tags: npm, bower, angular-fullstack

I tried both

'npm -g install bower' and 'sudo pm -g install bower'

still says

'zsh: command not found: bower'

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. Please try asking questions like this on related StackExchange websites like www.superuser.com.

Comment: can you be more clear on how this is not programming related?

Comment: This is not programming related since this is no question about programming languages, concepts or programming-specific software. For more information about what you should ask on stackoverflow, check out [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com) is a website like stackoverflow, but more tailored towards questions like this, about software in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is whether the path `npm` is installing `bower` to is on your `PATH`/`path`. Run

```
echo $PATH $path | grep $(echo $(npm config get prefix)/bin) && echo Found
```

That should output the word `Found`. If not, you can find out which directory to add by running:

```
echo $(npm config get prefix)/bin
```

The path can be changed in your `~/.zshenv` file.